# Constraints not updating automatically in ios

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have created a storyboard as in the image. In that I have set the vertical spacing between the red view and tableView is around 20. Its working good. 
[image]

But when i tried to change the height of red view then the tableview should comes up with the constraints I added but the table view is remained constant at the same place.

I used the following code

```
redView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 1008, height: 0)
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Can you show what other constraints you have given to red view and tableView

Comment: Do you have redView's height equal to the view's height? And you are changing the redView's height to 0?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are adding a constraint to any object on storyboard then onwards that object's frame will be maintained by autolayout engine. This is the primary design principle I guess. In this case what you can simply do is that just make an outlet of the desired constraint which you want to update and update that constraint within your code. For your understanding I am attaching a screenshot.

[image]

Now after making a constraint outlet it must look like as follows.

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Now to update the height you just have to do one thing.

```
containerViewHeight.constant = 0
```

In my opinion if this update is not working inside `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` then please update inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` because when `viewDidLoad` get called then iOS doesn't apply the layout properly.

In my case what I will do is -

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() { //This ensures all the layout has been applied properly.
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    containerViewHeight.constant = 0
}
```

Note: - To achieve some nice animation effect during layout changes you can apply this constraint update inside an `UIView` animation block like as follows. But remember, to see the effect nicely you have to call this after presenting the view properly like after `viewDidAppear` etc.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.2, usingSpringWithDamping: 8.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
    containerViewHeight.constant = 0
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

Sorry for any mistake.
Update/Edit is most welcome.

Hope this helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Autolayout to manipulate the redView's height. Modifying its frame's size is not Autolayout. Modify its height constraint (if it exists)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use constraints or changes to frames! You cannot do both!

What you need to do is to make an outlet reference to your constraint and change its constant-value instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you placed the code in viewdidload or viewwillappear, you will find issues like this. You need to put the code after all the constraints are loaded.

Also, make an object of the height constraint and name it for example redViewHeight.
and change its value by: redViewHeight.constant = 0

It will work!

Comment: My code is in viewDidAppear() andI tried the code you specified

Comment: did you use proportional height between redview and mainview?

Comment: delete that proportionality constraint and add a constant height constraint.
then make an outlet of that constant height constraint for eg: redViewHeight.

Put redViewHeight.constant =0 where you want.
and for other cases, put redViewHeight.constant = proportionality ratio * screenHeight.

where screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height

Comment: can you give me the latest screenshot of that viewcontroller? with the changed constarints

Answer (score 0):

Replace the constraints for the views with the following.

1. Redview

   `Top constraint to ParentView`
   `Leading Constraint to ParentView`
   `Trailing constraint to ParentView`
   `Height Constraint`
2. TableView

   `Top constraint to RedView`
   `Leading Constraint to ParentView`
   `Trailing constraint to ParentView`
   `Bottom constraint to ParentView`

Now wire an `IBOutlet` for the HeightConstraint of RedView and modify its `constant` value. The `UITableView` will adjust its height as desired.